# How to set FileWriter object positon?

Tags: java, file, netbeans, filereader, filewriter

Suppose I have to count the number of instances of a word in a line. After reading a line if there are no instances of that word in that line I want to delete that line. How can I set FileWriter cusrsor position to FileReader and then append "\b"?

Answer (score 0):

I Would read the 'original' file, writing desired lines to a new file. Then delete the orignal file and rename the new file to the original files name.